# Cannot completely remove reactable column with CSS class

Tags: css, r, reactable

I've created a table using [reactable](https://glin.github.io/reactable/) with [Quarto Markdown](https://quarto.org/) in [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) and I'm attempting to use a CSS class to remove one column (Twitter) when the screen width is 700px or less (mobile devices). I'm using "visibility: hidden" in my CSS to remove the column, however this is only removing the column contents and not the column header nor the column itself. I'm left with an empty column with the  column title displayed. I need the column completely removed.

Here is my R code to create the table:

```
library(reactable)
library(crosstalk)
library(htmltools)

note_taking <- read.csv("data.csv")

tbl <- reactable(
  data,
  defaultPageSize = 15,
  showPageSizeOptions = TRUE,
  wrap = TRUE,
  defaultColDef = colDef(headerClass = "header",
  ),
  rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer"),
  theme = reactableTheme(
      borderColor = "#e9f3fd",
      highlightColor = "rgba(233, 243, 253, .8)",
  ),
  columns = list(
    Twitter = colDef(html=TRUE, cell = function(value) {
        url <- paste0("https://twitter.com/", value)
        tags$a(href = url, target = "_blank", paste0("@", value))
      },
       class = "twitter-col", width = 150
    ),
))
tbl
```

Here is my CSS class:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.twitter-col {
    visibility: hidden;
}}
```

I've tried changing the column width to 0 but it has no effect. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [reactable docs](https://glin.github.io/reactable/reference/colDef.html). You can apply additional CSS classes to the header using `headerClass`. Add `twitter-col-header` class into Twitter column header. Then instead of using `visibility: hidden`, use the `display: none` instead on all the columns (including column header and column cells)

- Add `headerClass = "twitter-col-header"` to `colDef` function
- Add Css rule for both for the header and the cell columns

```
library(reactable)
library(crosstalk)
library(htmltools)

note_taking <- read.csv("data.csv")

tbl <- reactable(
  data,
  defaultPageSize = 15,
  showPageSizeOptions = TRUE,
  wrap = TRUE,
  defaultColDef = colDef(headerClass = "header",
  ),
  rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer"),
  theme = reactableTheme(
      borderColor = "#e9f3fd",
      highlightColor = "rgba(233, 243, 253, .8)",
  ),
  columns = list(
    Twitter = colDef(html=TRUE, cell = function(value) {
        url <- paste0("https://twitter.com/", value)
        tags$a(href = url, target = "_blank", paste0("@", value))
      },
       class = "twitter-col", width = 150, 
       headerClass = "twitter-col-header"
    ),
))
tbl
```

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .twitter-col,
      .twitter-col-header {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I hereby bestow upon you a +100 bounty. Use it wisely good sir.